# Express $a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b$ in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-polynomials

Express $a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b$ in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials.

I started with expanding $(a + b + c)^3$ and got to

$a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b = \frac{1}{3}(a + b + c)^3 -a^3 -b^3 - c^3 -2abc$

I see that the first and last terms on the right hand side are expressions of $S_1$ and $S_3$, but I am having trouble with the $-a^3 -b^3 - c^3$ terms.

Comment: shouldn't that be $\frac{1}{3}((a + b + c)^3 -a^3 -b^3 - c^3) -2abc$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Note,

$$\begin{array}
&& a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b \\
& =ab(a+b)+bc(b+c) + ca(c+a) \\
& =ab(a+b+c-c)+bc(b+c+a-a) + ca(c+a+b-b) \\
& =ab(a+b+c)-abc+bc(b+c+a)-bca + ca(c+a+b) - cab\\
& =(ab+bc+ca)(a+b+c)-3abc
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}S_1S_2&=(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)\\
&=a^2b+a^2c+abc+ab^2+abc+b^2c+abc+ac^2+bc^2\\
&=a^2b+a^2c+ab^2+b^2c+ac^2+bc^2+3S_3\end{align}$$

Comment: @orangeskid Sometime one is blind to ones own typos and this seems to be one of those times. Could you please point out my typos in detail?

Comment: sorry, now i see it, it did not fil all on the page, all is correct, great!

Comment: @orangeskid Hopefully easier to read now.

Comment: there are size commands that can shrink a long line without changing anything else. Some of the commands are small and tiny. Let me find that, give me a minute  \huge
\small
\scriptsize
\tiny

Answer (score 0):

$a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b$$ 
$$=$$ 
$$(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-3abc$